# How to log an error from a catch block and at the same time rollback the transaction?

Tags: sql, t-sql, transactions, try-catch

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
        --DO_ACTION
        --COMMIT_TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        --LOG_ERROR (e.g. INSERT INTO ErrorTable (ERROR_MESSAGE(), ...))
        --ROLLBACK
    END CATCH
```

I'm trying to do the following however, the ROLLBACK command is rolling back the logging of my error so the "ErrorTable" does not have anything in it.

How would I go about doing what I want to do in this situation?

Comment: Did you try switching the order of the statements. Rollback first then log?

Comment: im trying to capture ERROR_MESSAGE() as well. ill try to change the order now.

Comment: @Icarus, that worked. I switched the items. I roll back first, then log the error. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to log in `ErrorTable`? If it is data, which not available yet after rollback, you can keep that in table variable, then insert into `ErrorTable` after rollback. The table variables not participate in transactions.